# How do I change an image loaded in ImageView?

Tags: java, android

How do I get a square picture to load and crop like the picture I attached? Please give me some ideas. I can't find anything on the internet.

[image]

Comment: you can refer this https://github.com/florent37/ArcLayout

Comment: That's not really what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that the whitespace to the right is overlayed on the photo. You could try to swap the layers? That might mean the photo overlaps with the text.

Comment: I don't quite know what you mean.